# View previous branches in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I'd like to list the last 5 branches I've been working on in time order.

I'd assume it's something like:

```
git branch -l <some time-related flag here>
```

But looking through the docs I don't see anything time-related.

Has anyone done this and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my aliases:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format="%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)" refs/heads/
```

It sorts local branches by last commit time (which is not last checkout time, but it should be good enough)

Output looks like

```
2015-02-13 branch2
2015-02-13 master
2015-02-10 branch1
```

If you want precisely last 5 of them, you can pipe to `| head -5`.

Comment: If you create an alias like: 'brt = for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format="%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)" refs/heads/' and then run 'git brt' you just get a list of the dates.

Comment: Does this work when used directly without being an alias? (I use it as bash alias, not git alias)

Comment: yes, bash alias did the job. sorry - being a bit wimpy. superb answer.

Comment: @Snowcrash As .gitconfig alias you need to quote the " chars:
alias brt = for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format=\"%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)\" refs/heads/